# C# volatile double

Tags: c#, .net, volatile

As only reference types and a few primitives (including float, but not double, I'm not sure the reason why, I'm happy to hear why) can be declared as volatile, if I wrap a double in a class then declare it as volatile (as below), will the double property be 'read write' thread safe as any other volatile, or should I still be looking at locking?

```
public class MyThreadedClass
{
    volatile VolatileDouble voldub;
}

public class VolatileDouble
{
    public double Double { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reason why double can't be declared volatile: it's 64 bits, which makes it more than the word size on x86, which prevents it from being declared volatile in the CLI if I remember correctly.

With your current answer, only the *reference* is treated as being volatile. That means the memory model will make sure it always uses the most recent reference, but it could still use a stale value.

I'd go with locking if I were you, but one alternative is to use [`Interlocked.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx) and [`Interlocked.Exchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk0121zy.aspx) acting on longs, in conjunction with [`BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble.aspx) and [`BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx). You could encapsulate this within a `VolatileDouble` struct. (I'd probably make it a struct rather than a class.)

Comment: Kind of suspected that only the reference was volatile, hence the question. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: if he made sure the VolatileDouble is immutable he shouldn't have problems, correct?

Comment: Thanks also for the Interlocked and BitConverter suggestions, sparked a whole new path of thought

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, I *believe* it would be okay in that case - at least using the .NET 2.0 memory model which is slightly stronger than the ECMA memory model.

Comment: Sorry for coming late to the party, but it is actually inherently a C# specification which states that atomic reads/writes are guaranteed only on types of size 4 or less. CIL makes stronger guarantee of atomic r/w on sizes of a pointer or smaller (i.e. 4 bytes on x86, 8 bytes on x86_64 (looking at you, double)). The compiler compiles from C# to CIL, so it can't know what the processor will be. The last piece of the puzzle is that only types that have guaranteed atomic r/w ops can be delcared volatile.

Answer (score 5):

To work as above, you'd need to have it immutable (no setter) - perhaps with some implicit conversion operators for convenience. Otherwise, people could change the value without changing the (volatile) reference.

```
public class MyThreadedClass
{
    volatile Box<double> volDouble = 123.45;
}

public class Box<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly T value;
    public Box(T value) { this.value = value; }
    public T Value {get {return value;}}

    // explicit as nulls are a problem...
    public static explicit operator T(Box<T> box) {
        return box.value; }
    public static implicit operator T?(Box<T> box) {
        return box == null ? new T?() : new T?(box.value); }
    public static implicit operator Box<T>(T value) {
        return new Box<T>(value); }
    public static implicit operator Box<T>(T? value) {
        return value.HasValue ? new Box<T>(value.Value) : null; }
}
```

Beyond that - locking would be the best option.

Comment: 123.45f; If you hadn't pointed it out I wouldn't have noticed ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're just declaring that the reference is volatile not the instance, so that will not solve the problem.

Comment: Suspected so, hence the question, thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

The volatile documentation is some how misleading...

when the msdn documentation says that it uses the most up to date value what does it mean??? I'm sure that in a simple value this does not lead to confusion, but what about a reference, as Brian Rasmussen you are just talking about the ref not the actual instance (and therefore the interesting data).

From my point of view using volatile is not a good idea and I'd go for the lock, anyway this article might help you: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,dd3aff8a-7f8d-4de6-a2e7-d199662b68f4.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You cannot make a volatile long or double (64 bits) but you can make a volatile int (32 bits) and by using two 32 bit ints you can successfully use bit manipulation to simulate 64 bits (tested and working):

```
public class VolatileLong
{
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    private volatile int lo32;
    private volatile int hi32;
    public long Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                return ((long)hi32 << 32) | ((long)lo32 & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                lo32 = (int)(value & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
                hi32 = (int)((value - ((long)lo32 & 0xFFFFFFFFL)) >> 32);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class VolatileDouble
{
    private readonly VolatileLong vl = new VolatileLong();
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return System.BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(vl.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            vl.Value = System.BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
        }
    }
}
```