# .net System.MemberwiseClone and interlocked writes

Tags: .net, atomic, interlocked

When performing a MemberwiseClone of an array of value types:

```
 var arr = new double[100];
```

If these doubles are being modified using an Interlocked write on other threads, will the MemberwiseCloned copy be at any risk of having torn doubles in it? I'm not concerned about having slightly stale values, just tearing and the interaction between interlocked and memberwiseclone (which I guess translates to a memory blit type operation?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. On 32bit operating systems this is even guaranteed to have the risk of tearing. On 64bit it is implementation defined. I wouldn't lightly risk it because even if you test that it doesn't happen then your test was only on your particular .NET version and on you particular hardware. **You can't really make sure.**

**On 64bit you can reliably prevent tearing by implementing your own version of clone** (which is likely to be not much slower).

Comment: ok so am I right thinking that memcpy on 32 bit is working in 32 bit chunks hence tearing risk of the doubles, whilst on 64 bit it will be working at 64 bit level so should be atomic to each value? How would you implement a safe 64 bit clone in .net?

Comment: With a for loop copying doubles. Simple. You can go faster with the same thing +unsafe code + the loop unrolled 8 times.

Comment: ok so memcpy isn't a single cpu level memory blit type command and is effectively a loop?

Comment: memcpy has a lot of possible implementations. Many will even copy 64bit chunks on 32bit hardware (using SSE). My point is that you cannot *rely* on it. Therefore you need to roll your own. Basically, every memcpy is a tight loop.

Comment: thanks, not sure why I was thinking it was some magic implementation as you've triggered my memories of looking at memcpy implementations back in my C++ days.