# Can await corrupt a value when called concurrently

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task-parallel-library, async-await

Put simply, I have something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    double SomeProperty {get; private set;}

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        SomeProperty = await someService.SomeAsyncMethod();
    }
}
```

Could `SomeProperty` get corrupted if I call `SomeMethod()` many times concurrently ?

Comment: It would be exactly the same if you just retrieved your `double` from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it could get corrupted if you're calling `SomeMethod()` many times concurrently on the same MyClass instance.

Comment: @zerkms So it could get corrupted right ?

Comment: @Sniffer: that's right. `await` does not add any new semantics here.

Comment: see also: [is-reading-a-double-not-thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676808/is-reading-a-double-not-thread-safe?lq=1) applies to setting a double as well

Comment: The fact that you're asking the question indicates that you are considering doing something dangerous as a result of a likely bad decision at the architectural level. **Design your application so that you do not share memory across threads**. Imagine that a thread was a instead process and you couldn't easily share memory; how would you design your application then?

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for your input, greatly appreciated. I have no influence on the architecture nor the design of this. This is just something I was curious over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, potentially.

This isn't really related to `async-await`. You are simply setting a value to a property by multiple threads. The value can get corrupted and you should use some synchronization construct (i.e. `lock`):

```
public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    var temp = await someService.SomeAsyncMethod();
    lock (_lock)
    {
        SomeProperty = temp;
    }
}
```

Or an `Interlocked.Exchange` (using the backing field of the property):

```
public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backingField, await someService.SomeAsyncMethod());
}
```

However, if this method runs in a GUI thread (or any other case with a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`) then there's no chance of corruption since there's only a single thread handling that property.

Answer (score 3):

> Could SomeProperty get corrupted if I call SomeMethod() many times concurrently ?

Potentially, yes, though it depends on a lot of factors.

Writing a double is not guaranteed to be an atomic operation.  Since you are calling this method concurrently, you could be writing the value concurrently, which could cause undefined behavior.

There are various mechanisms to handle this.  Often, you only need to call the service once, in which case you can store the task directly:

```
Task<double> backing;
double SomeProperty { get { return backing.Result; } }

MyClass()       // in constructor
{
    backing = someService.SomeAsyncMethod(); // Note, no await here!
}
```

Otherwise, if you want multiple calls, an explicit `lock` or other synchronization mechanism is likely the best approach.

Comment: Although a different question. What's the best way to fix things in this situation ?

Comment: @Sniffer what do you want to achieve? Assuming there are 2 concurrent threads assign, which one must win?

Comment: Writing a double is guaranteed to be atomic on 64 bit machines though, isn't it? I recall that being mentioned on a similar question

Comment: @zerkms I just want to assure atomic writes to `SomeProperty` because I learned it could get corrupted.

Comment: Even if it's atomic, you'd need some kind of barrier. Just updating the value can cause inconsistent views from different threads.

Answer (score 2):

`async` and `await` do not add any concurrency protection.  If it can get corrupted without `async` and `await`, it can get get corrupted with them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Because you're using `await`, the method gets called, grabs the `Task` from `someService.SomeAsyncMethod()`, and then yields control until said `Task` completes.

When that task does complete, control returns (normally on the same thread of the calling task, though this depends on `SynchronizationContext` as pointed out by @Reed) and then calls the `set` function of `SomeProperty`. At this point, said call could occur from multiple threads, or from a thread other than the one that started the tasks, resulting in unpredictable get/set behaviour without `lock`s.

Comment: I like your explanation because at first I thought `SomeProperty` would be set in a continuation. Thank you.

Comment: Control returning is not based on threads, but rather the current SynchronizationContext.

Comment: ok, *normally* control returns to the thread that called the task. I'll incorporate this.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing a double is not thread safe so it is best to use a lock around those. Using `Interlocked.COmpareExchange` will write the variable correctly but you need to read it in a thread safe manner as well, so basically you need a lock. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676808/is-reading-a-double-not-thread-safe) from Eric Lippert.