# How to correctly read an Interlocked.Increment'ed int field?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Suppose I have a non-volatile int field, and a thread which `Interlocked.Increment`s it. Can another thread safely read this directly, or does the read also need to be interlocked?

I previously thought that I had to use an interlocked read to guarantee that I'm seeing the current value, since, after all, the field isn't volatile. I've been using `Interlocked.CompareExchange(int, 0, 0)` to achieve that.

However, I've stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186515/interlocked-and-volatile/1186562#1186562) which suggests that actually plain reads will always see the current version of an `Interlocked.Increment`ed value, and since int reading is already atomic, there's no need to do anything special. I've also found [a request in which Microsoft rejects a request for Interlocked.Read(ref int)](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/256490/interlocked-read-only-does-long-data-type), further suggesting that this is completely redundant.

So can I really safely read the most current value of such an `int` field without `Interlocked`?

Comment: Care to select an answer? :)

Comment: @sunside no, I don't feel I can select an answer with confidence as I was never convinced either way. Also there's no point in selecting the top voted answer as it's at the top anyway. At best my tickmark would deceive users into thinking that I know the answer to be correct.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to guarantee that the other thread will read the latest value, you must use [`Thread.VolatileRead()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread.aspx). (*)

The read operation itself is atomic so that will not cause any problems but without volatile read you may get old value from the cache or compiler may optimize your code and eliminate the read operation altogether. From the compiler's point of view it is enough that the code works in single threaded environment. Volatile operations and memory barriers are used to limit the compiler's ability to optimize and reorder the code.

There are several participants that can alter the code: compiler, JIT-compiler and CPU. It does not really matter which one of them shows that your code is broken. The only important thing is the *.NET memory model* as it specifies the rules that must be obeyed by all participants.

(*) `Thread.VolatileRead()` does not really get the latest value. It will read the value and add a memory barrier after the read. The first volatile read may get cached value but the second would get an updated value because the memory barrier of the first volatile read has forced a cache update if it was necessary. In practice this detail has little importance when writing the code.

Comment: +1, this is useful depending on "why" he cares about an atomic read. (added the MSDN link as well)

Comment: I *must*? As in, if I use `Interlocked.Read` (on a long) or `Interlocked.CompareExchange` (on an int) then I _won't_ necessarily get the latest value?

Comment: @romkyns: `Interlocked` methods are safe and they always operate with fresh values. However, if you just read the variable value elsewhere, the value you get is not necessarily the same that you have updated with the `Interlocked` methods. Even though the `Interlocked` method has written the value to the main memory, your thread might be executed in another core that has not updated its read cache and you will get the old value. This is really a problem if you use the variable as exit condition for a loop or you expect certain execution order for instructions.

Comment: @mgronber If that's so, then the [answer I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186515/interlocked-and-volatile/1186562#1186562) is wrong. Also, the [rejected MS Connect suggestion](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/256490/interlocked-read-only-does-long-data-type) is not actually redundant. Do you agree?

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of the MS Connect link. `Interlocked.Read(Int64)` is needed on 32bit cores to ensure you don't get **half** of the `Int64`. Only 32bit reads are *atomic*. It has nothing to do with getting the **latest** value. [You're mixing up synchronization and atomicity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/26/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-one.aspx).

Comment: @romkyns: Yes, I think that the answer is wrong if we think about the .NET memory model. Normal read operations can be optimized away if there are no memory barriers so the `Interlocked` updates are not enough. One must use volatile reads or specify the variable to be volatile.

Comment: @romkyns: Like sixlettervariables said, the `Interlocked` methods exist to provide atomicity so the MS Connect suggestion is rightfully rejected. The synchronization is only a side effect of some `Interlocked` methods.

Comment: @mgronber So does `Interlocked.Read(Int64)` perform a volatile read?

Comment: @binki: I.12.6.5 Locks and threads: "*5. Explicit atomic operations. The class library provides a variety of atomic operations in the System.Threading.Interlocked class. These operations (e.g. Increment, Decremenet, Exchange, and CompareExchange) perform implicit acquire/release operations.*" The Ecma specification does not say anything explicit about `Interlocked.Read(Int64)`. I would assume that it  does a normal read on 64-bit systems, because the purpose of the `Interlocked` class is to provide atomicity and the 64-bit reads are already atomic on 64-bit systems. So my answer is no.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.volatileread), the `Thread.VolatileRead` is a legacy APIs and has been replaced by the [`Volatile.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read).

Answer (score 17):

A bit of a meta issue, but a good aspect about using `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 0, 0)` (ignoring the obvious disadvantage that it's harder to understand when used for reading) is that it works regardless of `int` or `long`. It's true that `int` reads are always atomic, but `long` reads are not or may be not, depending on the architecture. Unfortunately, `Interlocked.Read(ref value)` only works if `value` is of type `long`.

Consider the case that you're starting with an `int` field, which makes it impossible to use `Interlocked.Read()`, so you'll read the value directly instead since that's atomic anyway. However, later in development you or somebody else decides that a `long` is required - the compiler won't warn you, but now you may have a subtle bug: The read access is not guaranteed to be atomic anymore. I found using `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` the best alternative here; It may be slower depending on the underlying processor instructions, but it is safer in the long run. I don't know enough about the internals of `Thread.VolatileRead()` though; It might be "better" regarding this use case since it provides even more signatures.

I would not try to read the value directly (i.e. without any of the above mechanisms) within a loop or any tight method call though, since even if the writes are volatile and/or memory barrier'd, nothing is telling the compiler that the value of the field can actually change between two *reads*. So, the field should be either `volatile` or any of the given constructs should be used.

My two cents.

Answer (score 8):

You're correct that you do not need a special instruction to atomically read a 32bit integer, however, what that means is you will get the "whole" value (i.e. you won't get *part of one write and part of another*). You have no guarantees that the value won't have changed once you have read it.

It is at this point where you need to decide if you need to use some other synchronization method to control access, say if you're using this value to read a member from an array, etc.

---

In a nutshell, **atomicity** ensures an operation happens completely and indivisibly. Given some operation `A` that contained `N` steps, if you made it to the operation right after `A` you can be assured that all `N` steps happened in isolation from concurrent operations.

If you had two threads which executed the atomic operation `A` you are guaranteed you will see only the **complete** result of *one of the two* threads. If you want to coordinate the threads, atomic operations could be used to create the required synchronization. But atomic operations in and of themselves do not provide higher level synchronization. The `Interlocked` family of methods are made available to provide some fundamental atomic operations.

**Synchronization** is a broader kind of concurrency control, often built around *atomic* operations. Most processors include memory barriers which allow you to ensure all cache lines are flushed and you have a **consistent** view of memory. Volatile reads are a way to ensure consistent access to a given memory location.

While not immediately applicable to your problem, reading up on ACID (atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability) with respect to databases may help you with the terminology.

Comment: Meta-comment: if your question is what synchronization method should you use @mgronber covers it.

Comment: Should I use any synchronization if I read variable `int a` right after (in the next line) `Interlocked.Increment(a)` in the same method?

Answer (score 1):

Me, being paranoid, I do `Interlocked.Add(ref incrementedField, 0)` for int values

Comment: Most probably being paranoid just costs you a little bit of performance, in exchange for nothing. The [`Volatile.Read(ref incrementedField)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read) should do the same job more economically. Check out this answer for reference: [Difference between Interlocked.Exchange and Volatile.Write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425738/difference-between-interlocked-exchange-and-volatile-write/71002288#71002288)

Comment: In my specific use case, performance loss is unnoticeable (rare calls, couple of times per second), so I can live with that ;)

Comment: Sure, if performance is not an issue then the `Interlocked.Add(ref intVariable, 0)` is just as good as the `Volatile.Read(ref intVariable)`, and also easier to reason about its correctness. The problem is that it doesn't communicate clearly its intentions. So you'll have to add comments, in order to help future maintainers understand the intentions of this mysterious line of code. Which will let the maintainers know that you were paranoid, and that you didn't really knew what you were doing. Which is something not very desirable in general. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, hi! :) Researching the same thing, I've just stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509039/1768303) and it does make sense to me. So probably not the same as `Volatile.Read`, in theory. Though I'd probably use `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, 0, 0)` instead of `Interlocked.Add(ref val, 0)` for a read operation.

Comment: @noseratio I've posted a relevant answer to this question: [Why not volatile on System.Double and System.Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727068/why-not-volatile-on-system-double-and-system-long/71724816#71724816) Judging from the comments in the source code of the `Volatile` class, the `Volatile.Read` is atomic too.

Comment: @noseratio I just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507457/difference-between-threading-volatile-readint64-and-threading-interlocked-read/72508084#72508084) in the question you linked too. I added a cautionary note to be on the safe side. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias tks! I've learnt a lot from both answers 

Answer (score -7):

Yes everything you've read is correct. Interlocked.Increment is designed so that normal reads will not be false while making the changes to the field. Reading a field is not dangerous, writing a field is.